# How can i solve Huawei AppGallery Failed to obtain the authentication code

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, appgallery

I am getting `Failed to obtain the authentication code` while uploading signed app.

Here is the image:

[image]

Comment: If it is the first-time uploading SW package, please logout AGC, then login again. Try uploading the package from there. If problem still exists, let me know, further troubleshooting will be carried out.

Comment: Could you please provide your appid to check more info?

Comment: Please try to 1. Firstly delete the credentials; 2. Secondly delete the project; 3. [Create app on AGC](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/app/agc-create_app); to see if it works.

Comment: I solve the problem thanks

Comment: What was the solution? Please provide the solution to help others.

Comment: What was the solution?Please